# Understanding how extern works

Tags: c

The way I understand extern is that we are able to declare a variable anywhere in  a program and use it, but we can just define it once. I am getting an error in the following program.

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "function.h"
extern int c;
int main() 
{ 
    int c;


    c=10;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printExternValue();

    return 0;

}
```

function .h

```
void printExternValue();
```

function .c

```
#include "function.h"
#include "stdio.h"
extern int c;
void printExternValue()
{
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
```

I expect this program to print out:

10
10

But it's not doing so since it's giving an error. I re-declared the variable c in the function.c file with the intention of using the value that is stored in the so called external storage.

Error: function.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `c'

I am currently reading a PDF file from tutorialspoints which I think to be very redundant since the intention of creating a variable with the aggregate extern is useless. The right way this should be done is that they define the variables outside the function is that right?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

// Variable declaration: 
extern int a, b; 
extern int c; 
extern float f; 

int main () 
{ 
  /* variable definition: */ 
  int a, b; 
  int c; 
  float f; 

  /* actual initialization */ 
  a = 10; 
  b = 20; 

  c = a + b; 
  printf("value of c : %d \n", c); 

  f = 70.0/3.0; 
  printf("value of f : %f \n", f); 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You're getting a link-time error about 'undefined symbol `c`'?  You should quote the error message exactly, for the code you show.  The `c` defined and referenced inside `main()` is nothing to do with the `extern int c;` declared outside `main()`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated the thread.

Comment: Since your code never defines `c`, it isn't surprising that it isn't found.  You need an `int c;` or `int c = 314159265;` or something similar outside a function in one of the files you link to create your program.

Comment: Ok, so I defined int c in the main, but it's out of scope for any function defined in other file. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you didn't (define `int c` in the main file).  The `int c;` inside `main()` is a local (automatic) variable that hides (shadows) the one declared outside `main()` with `extern int c;`.   The two share the same name, but are otherwise 100% unrelated.  And yes, the `c` defined inside `main()` can only be accessed by _name_ from inside `main()`; it's a local variable, valid only in the function.

Comment: OHHH ok, so adding the extern int c inside the main function will do the job.

Comment: No, you still need to define `c` outside of a function.

Comment: No; 'adding the `extern int c` inside the main file' will not do the job.  You need an un-externed `int c;` or `int c = 3;` (for any chosen initializer) in either the file containing `main()` (but outside the `main()` function, or any other function), or you need a similar definition in some other file (presumably `function.c`), again with the definition outside any function in the file.  Your header should be responsible for declaring the variable: `extern int c;` belongs in the header (and you should not write it in your source files). One of your source files is responsible for defining it.

Comment: See also [How to use `extern` to share variables between source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#1433387).  Stop no later than the second invitation to read no further — the remaining material would confuse you at this stage.

Comment: I am currently reading a PDF file from tutorialspoints which I think to be very redundant since the intention of creating a variable with the aggregate extern is useless. The right way how this should be done is to define the variables outside the function. is that right?. Check my updated thread.

Comment: By the way, I read your post though. That's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Variable declread as

```
extern int c;
```

is an *external* declaration that potentially requires an *external* definiton. "External" in this case means "located outside of any function". Your `c` declared locally in `main()` does not fullfill that role.

Since you are *using* that externally declared variable `c` in your code you have to *define* it and define it only *once*.

You need

```
int c;
```

or

```
int c = 0;
```

or

```
extern int c = 0;
```

it one of your implementation files, at file scope. All of these are definitions. Any of them will *define* your variable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Is my last updated claim in the thread right?

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable *once* in one of your files (to reserve space),

```
int c = 0;
```

Declare your variable references *everywhere else* (in all of your other files) (to reference said space),

```
extern int c;
```

But that could be confusing, so name them indicative of the 'global' use,

```
int glob_a, glob_b;
int glob_c;
float glob_f;
```

And declare your variable references everywhere else,

```
extern int glob_a, glob_b;
extern int glob_c;
extern float glob_f;
```

But you really want to avoid littering you namespace, so when you have a collection of globals, declare a struct that contains them (in a header file probably called globals.h),

```
typedef struct globals_struct {
    int a, b;
    int c;
    float f;
} globals_t;
```

And once (in your file main.c that declares main()), you define the struct,

```
#include globals.h
globals_t globs;
```

And everywhere else, reference the space,

```
#include globals.h
extern globals_t globs;
```

Often, you will see a stanza such as this, where MAIN is only declared in one file,

```
#ifndef MAIN
extern globals_t globs;
#else
globals_t globs;
#endif
```

Use your globals,

```
int my_a = globs.a;
int my_b = globs.b;
int my_f = globs.f;
```

Notice how you have avoided needless namespace pollution?

Because extern just tells the compiler (actually the linker) that a variable is being defined elsewhere and needs to be linked against.